# Is it really necessary to learn how to write a quadratic in standard to vertex form?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, completing-the-square

How crucial is this skill or form of writing and polynomial function? Can't we just always use the $-b/2a$ trick for the $x$ intercept and just plug it back into the function to find the $y$?

Comment: I think it's more of a test of how well you know how to complete the square, which is definitely important.

Comment: That is a good point for sure thanks.

Comment: Did you mean setting $x = -\frac{b}{2a}$ in order to find the $x$-coordinate of the vertex?

Comment: This is also helpful in finding the equation of the parabola when you're given the vertex and one other point on the curve.

Comment: Almost nothing you have been taught in your whole life and you will be taught in your future life is crucial. On the other hand, I assure you that not being able to manipulate with ease quadratic polynomials is very close to analphabetism in math.

Comment: More than just completing the square, it may be your first introduction to linear transformations for functions more complex than straight lines.

Comment: Rather than just memorising the "$-b/(2a)$ trick", it is better to learn its derivation, which (without calculus) involves completing the square of an arbitrary quadratic.

Comment: It will also help you to recognize different forms of quadratic equations, and what they mean -- that is, what each form tells you at first glance. For example, vertex form gives you the vertex (of course), and standard form gives you the $y$-intercept ($y=c$). Understanding these things now will be beneficial in higher maths.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question, it isn't **crucial** in any serious way. However, it is as handy as, say, "point-slope form" or "slope-intercept form" for lines, it gives you a way to immediately recognize certain bits of information. Additionally, as Daniel M. mentions, it covers completing the square which is more often than not, the desired way to solve for the roots etc. of a quadratic (it's also just a handy algebraic manipulation.

Perhaps to demonstrate some utility of completing the square, we'll derive the quadratic formula starting from standard form:

$$ax^2+bx+c=0 \implies x^2+\frac{b}{a}x=-\frac{c}{a}$$

but *now*, we really need to complete the square:

$$x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+\frac{b^2}{4a^2}=\frac{b^2}{4a^2}-\frac{c}{a} \implies(x+\frac{b}{2a})^2=\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2} \implies x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}.$$

Notice how one could deduce the $\frac{-b}{2a}$ trick from the middle implication! You're right to notice that the two are intimately related, I think it's best to know both.

Let's use a similar technique to examine what's going on.

**vertex form:** $y=a_1(x-h)^2+k$. But, given a quadratic in standard form, $y=ax^2+bx+c$, we can deduce the following by adding and subtracting the same thing, while factoring out an $a$, and then completing the square:

\begin{align*}y&=ax^2+bx+c\\
&=a\left(x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+\frac{c}{a}\right)+\left(\frac{b^2}{4a}-\frac{b^2}{4a}\right)\\
&=a\left(x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+\frac{b^2}{4a^2}+\frac{c}{a}-\frac{b^2}{4a^2}\right)\\
&=a\left((x+\frac{b}{2a})^2+\frac{c}{a}-\frac{b^2}{4a^2} \right)\\
&=a(x+\frac{b}{2a})^2+c-\frac{b^2}{4a}.
\end{align*}

Notice that this is a way to always get to "vertex form" and tells you exactly what $a,h,k$ are supposed to be in vertex form.

Namely:
$a_1=a$ (Hoorah!)

$h=-\frac{b}{2a}$ (As you have noticed)

$k=c-\frac{b^2}{4a}$

Answer (score 2):

The ability to go from standard form to vertex form is critical! When you want to solve a quadratic equation, the first technique you learn is factoring. But not every quadratic equation is factorable, so how do we solve those?

The vertex form of the equation is always solvable:
$$
a(x-h)^2+k=0 \iff (x-h)^2=-\frac{k}{a} \iff x-h=\pm\sqrt{-\frac{k}{a}} \iff x=h\pm\sqrt{-\frac{k}{a}}.
$$

So the ability to go from standard form to vertex form is what allows us to solve any quadratic equation.

Comment: Technically the standard "quadratic formula" already allows us to solve any quadratic equation in standard form--vertex form not required. But the beauty of the vertex form is in recognizing that the final solution at the right in Laars' answer IS the **vertex form of the quadratic formula**! This can be shown by substituting h and k with corresponding a,b,c expressions. This form is so much more transparent--each term is directly related to a feature of the parabola. Of course not every quadratic is meant to be a parabola, but its simplicity compared to the standard form speaks for itself.

Answer (score 1):

The way your question is written leaves me uncertain what your question is.

What is "standard to vertex form"?

One can write $y = ax^2 + bx + c$ and show that that is equivalent to $y= a\left( x + \dfrac b {2a} \right)^2 + c - \dfrac{b^2}{4a}.$  Is the latter what you mean by "standard to vertex form"?

What is the $\dfrac{-b}{2a}$ trick? The number $\dfrac{-b}{2a}$ is the $x$-coordinate of the vertex.  Did you have in mind that knowing that that is the $x$-coordinate of the vertex?  At any rate, this doesn't give us any $x$-intercepts (as suggested in your question) without doing a bit more than that.  Your phrase "the $x$-intercept" suggests that there is only one of those, and that's not true.

If my guesses as to your meaning are correct, it still leaves me wondering what you're asking. You seem to suggest that one can use the knowledge that the $x$-coordinate of the vertex is $-b/(2a)$ to do something that could otherwise be done by knowing that $ax^2+bx+c = a\left( x + \dfrac b {2a} \right)^2 + c - \dfrac{b^2}{4a},$ and that using the aforentioned knowledge is a preferable way to do it.  But what is it that you're trying to do that could be done by either of those methods?

And how would one know that $-b/(2a)$ is the $x$-coordinate of the vertex without showing it by using the fact that $ax^2+bx+c = a\left( x + \dfrac b {2a} \right)^2 + c - \dfrac{b^2}{4a}\text{?}$

Comment: I think the OP simply means that if one wanted to find the vertex, you would not need to "convert" or manipulate a quadratic into "vertex form." Probably your point is salient, but you might be that most students aren't taught vertex form in exactly that way. Instead, it's the more elusive: $y=a(x-h)^2+k$, which doesn't quite demonstrate the relationship between the standard and vertex forms.

Comment: also, typo: $\frac{b^2}{4a}$  should be the last term subtracted off of your "vertex form" throughout

Answer (score 1):

It's important for the simple reason that, given

$ax^2 + bx + c$, it isn't immediately obvious what the graph looks like. Converting to vertex form, however, it is: $$a\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2 + c - \frac{b^2}{4a}$$

You have your standard $x^2$ parabola scaled and shifted.

Why, then, don't we always have vertex form? This is because it is more natural and conventional to write polynomials as

$$P(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i$$

With this, for example, differentiation and integration is simpler. Plus vertex form, to my knowledge, does not generalize in an obvious way to polynomials of arbitrary degree.

Comment: typo: $-\frac{b^2}{4a}$, not $4a^2$.

Comment: @AndresMejia Thanks